# Groupby then select data using lambda/linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'm trying to group some db data using the following statement.

```
var res = from messages in db.Messages
group messages by messages.Message_Sent_Date into grp
select new { message_count = grp.Sum(g => g.Message_Count), message_cost = grp.Sum(g => g.Customer_Price) };
```

which is equivalent to:

```
var query = db.Messages.Where(m => m.Message_Sent_Date != null && m.Message_Count != 99)
                       .GroupBy(d => d.Message_Sent_Date)
                       .Select(g => new {
                               message_count = g.Sum(c => c.Message_Count),
                               message_cost = g.Sum(c => c.Customer_Price),
                           });
```

My question is, the object selected has 2 fields namely message_count and message_cost. If I want to add a third field 'Message_Sent_Date' which is essentially the column by which the data is grouped into. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `g.Key` which will be the Message_Sent_Date for each group, so the snippet will be like this:

```
 // Modified select after the GroupBy clause 
.Select(g =>
        new
        {
            message_count = g.Sum(c => c.Message_Count),
            message_cost = g.Sum(c => c.Customer_Price),
            Message_Sent_Date= g.Key
        });
```

Comment: Glad to hear and.. happy to help you...!